# Pandas removing all special characters from columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with a '%' columns is all columns and the last row of one columns has '<1%'

```
Out[277]: 

   Year Conventional  HMO  PPO  POS HDHP/SO
0  1988          73%  16%  11%             
1  1993          46%  21%  26%   7%        
2  1996          27%  31%  28%  14%        
3  1999          10%  28%  39%  24%        
4  2000           8%  29%  42%  21%  6% 
.   .
.   . 
.   . 
22  2018          <1%  16%  49% 29%
```

I want to remove all the special special characters in the columns. I have tried:

```
df1.columns= df1.columns.str.replace('\w,'')
```

and

```
df.columns= df.columns.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
```

With both of these I have been successful in getting rid of '%' sign. But not '<'.
Doing something like this:

```
df1['Conventional']= df1['Conventional'].map(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]))
```

Throws an error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Ideally I want to remove all special characters in the entire dataframe in one line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) first by `<%`:

```
df = df.replace(r'[<%]', '', regex=True)
```

Or by all non numeric values:

```
df = df.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)
```

And then set to `float`s all columns without first:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to remove the special chars but no luck with converting to float. This is the error I get: 'ValueError: could not convert string to float:'. Tried to convert to int with .astype(int) and it throws this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: @aRad - How working `df = df.replace([r'[<%]', r'^\s*$'], ['',np.nan], regex=True)` ?

Comment: it replace empty strings to `NaN`